# 502 error nginx + ruby on rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, activeadmin

Application details :
Rails 3.1.0
Ruby 1.9.2
unicorn 4.2.0
resque 1.20.0
nginx/1.0.14
redis 2.4.8

I am using **active_admin gem**, for all URL's getting response 200,
but only one URL giving 502 error on production.

rake routes :

```
admin_links GET        /admin/links(.:format)                                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/links"}
```

And its working on local(development).

localhost log : response code 200

```
    Started GET "/admin/links" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-12 11:05:21 +0530
        Processing by Admin::LinksController#index as */*
        Parameters: {"link"=>{}}
    Geokit is using the domain: localhost
        AdminUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
         (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `links` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
         (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `links` 
         (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM `links` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count 
        CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM `links` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count 
        Link Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` ORDER BY `links`.`id` desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
        Link Load (6677.2ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` 
    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activeadmin-0.4.2/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (14919.0ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 15663ms (Views: 8835.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6682.8ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

production log : 502 response

```
    Started GET "/admin/links" for 103.9.12.66 at 2013-02-12 05:25:37 +0000
        Processing by Admin::LinksController#index as */*
        Parameters: {"link"=>{}}
```

NGinx error log

```
2013/02/12 07:36:16 [error] 32401#0: *1948 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

don't know what's happening, could some buddy help me out.

Comment: Could you post your `rake routes` and the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: added *log* and `rake routes`

Comment: Unicorn and Nginx config please

Comment: In this case, upstream error means that your Unicorn processes are not running properly.  Can you paste your unicorn config? Also can you observe the output of top command to see if there is any memory spikes with the application?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @rkp Please help.....

Comment: @rkp: Can you please try solution for this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797234/display-has-to-many-association-activeadmin-rails-not-working-in-staging-but-wor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a timeout problem.

**Tackling it**

> HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway

Indicates, that nginx had a problem to talk to its configured upstream.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#502

> 2013/02/12 07:36:16 [error] 32401#0: *1948 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Nginx error log tells you Nginx was actually able to connect to the configured upstream but the process closed the connection before the answer was (fully) received.

Your development environment:

> Completed 200 OK in 15663ms

Apparently you need around 15 seconds to generate the response on your development machine.

> In contrast to proxy_connect_timeout, this timeout will catch a server
>   that puts you in it's connection pool but does not respond to you with
>   anything beyond that. Be careful though not to set this too low, as
>   your proxy server might take a longer time to respond to requests on
>   purpose (e.g. when serving you a report page that takes some time to
>   compute). You are able though to have a different setting per
>   location, which enables you to have a higher proxy_read_timeout for
>   the report page's location.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_read_timeout

On the nginx side the proxy_read_timeout is at a default of 60 seconds, so that's safe

I have no idea how ruby (on rails) works, check the error log - the timeout happens in that part of your stack

Comment: can you please try solution to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797234/display-has-to-many-association-activeadmin-rails-not-working-in-staging-but-wor