# Display has to many association activeadmin rails not working in staging but works fine in local and development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, has-many

I have users which can have many identities, (depending on whether they login using facebook, google, or my site). In ActiveAdmin to display the identities I had the following code.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
menu label: 'Subscribers'
ActiveAdmin.register Identity do
belongs_to :user
 end 


index do
selectable_column
column :email
column :current_sign_in_at
column :sign_in_count
column :created_at
column "Sign-up Provider", :identities do |user|
      ul do

         user.identities.collect  do |identity|
             li do 
                 if identity.provider == "gplus"
                   "Google"
                 else identity.provider == "facebook"
                  identity.provider.capitalize
                 end
            end   
          end
         "Self"
       end
 end
actions
end

form do |f|
  f.inputs 'User Details' do
  f.input :email
  f.input :password
  f.input :password_confirmation
  end
  f.actions
 end
end
```

It works fine in the local host, and a remote development environment. But gives 502 error when run on staging which uses the production environment. 
seeing the log it seems the query takes long time. Trying to figure out why does it take longer time, it appeared as if the query to fetch the identity is executed for each user again and again, which is kind of an inefficient way. We also tried using the data at the staging and importing it in the local and development enviroment to see if it is the data size that is causing error, but it still works there. I understand the query is inefficient. What is the correct way to achieve this?

And if what I have used is the correct way to go for it, please help me resolve the error. Thanks.

Surprisingly, this error does not occur if i remove the identities column.

Comment: seems there is a problem in loading all records in memory "apply pagination", this should be fixed with paginations

Comment: @rkp: We noticed that somehow 98% memory of the server was being used. We deleted some log files to free the memory and also changed the query to pluck on ly the provider from identity. It works fine now. Could the memory be an issue?

Comment: what do you mean by "98% memory of the server was being used" is this "Disk-space" or "RAM" ?
Deleting log files will increase "Disk-space" and selecting only required fields will affect your memory because now you are loading less data in memory(RAM)

Comment: @rkp: Yeah, I meant disk-space only. Was this a memory issue?

Comment: yes this could also cause problem as there is no space left in disk so that OS doesn't have enough virtual memory to use.

Comment: @rkp: okay, thanks... Well anyways, is the code I have written efficient or there is some other efficient way to achieve the same, using joins or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this problem had quite unusual solution, probably not specifically related to this problem but yes

The problem was with memory. On the server, the disk space became over-exceedingly used. We freed some memory by deleting some old log files, and also, used `pluck` instead of `collect`, just to fetch only the needed "provider" instead of the whole record.